# Convert .exe to injectable Dll

Tags: c++, dll, code-injection

I've got a Win32 exe which I want to convert into an injectable Dll file.
This is what I tried:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD dwAttached, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{   
   if (dwAttached == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
       CreateThread(NULL, 0, &WinMain, NULL, 0, NULL); //This doen't work...
   }
   return 1;
}
```

I don't know how to make it call WinMain on attach.
How do I do it the right way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you think this should work?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your use case? For a very fast answer you could certainly do it, though it will be painful. Executable are not meant to be used that way

Comment: I have an application which makes a clear d3dx9 Window. I want to run it from inside another process tho.

Comment: I smell an unbalanced stack.

Comment: See [LoadLibrary() an EXE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110747/loadlibrary-an-exe)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this :

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD dwAttached, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
   if (dwAttached == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)WinMain, NULL, 0, NULL); //starts the routine in anew thread
   }
   return 1;
}
```