# Undefined behaviour while calling a function from dll

Tags: c, dll, mingw, undefined-behavior, memory-access

Though the title reads dll, the actual library loaded is an exe. Suppose I have an exe file `testlib.exe`. I need to call a function from it, let it be `func()`. What I am doing is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char* (__stdcall *f_func)();

int main()
{
  HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("testlib.exe");
  f_func func = (f_func)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "func");

  printf(func());

  return 0;
}
```

Now most of the times I run the program it gives the correct output, but in some cases (1 out of 8 for example) it gives either garbage text or values of some other variables in `testlib.exe`. I identify it's due to wrong memory reference but can neither explain nor solve it.

My os is windows and I'm using mingw gcc. I do not use MSVS as it does not fit well in code portability.

PS: The `testlib.exe` is well built and I cannot change it. It is unlikely to have any problem. I tried different versions and also it's running in other build systems well. Also it is a release build, so less hope in debugging.

**UPDATE:**
I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110747) question, it says that it is possible by patching the IAT table. My point is completly different. I am using a function that is neither initialised by main nor by dllmain.
Actually what I found that `GetProcAddress` gives right function pointer everytime. What gets messed is the return object. For example if the function in exe library is:

```
const char* func() {
    return "Sometext";
}
```

then sometimes the reference to `"sometext` is sometimes wrong. I do suspect randomised loading but I'm not sure. I renamed the exe as dll but no change observed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LoadLibrary() an EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110747/loadlibrary-an-exe)

Comment: My program has apparently nothing to do with dllmain(). It calls a exported function. And I also tried with the lib file but same result (additionally sometimes 0x0000005 error occured, due to same reason I think).

Comment: But, as stated in the suggested duplicate (specifically, in the linked article in the top answer), loading an `exe` file *via* a `LoadLibrary` call will not necessarily result in correct initialization of that module's code base.

Comment: I assumed that it may not be an issue as my test function just reads a constant and returns it. I chose the simplest case possible.

Comment: Also I mentioned that the same exe is being loaded without any issue in a couple of other systems, key difference is they use MSVC and the `/DELAYLOAD:testlib.exe` flag.

Comment: If you use `LoadLibrary` with an executable, then besides not loading the static imports, it also doesn't do base relocation.